# trasforming text into matrix to become .csv in R

Tags: r, export-to-csv, strsplit

I have the following text:

```
Anada - Asociación de nada Address: calle 13 13 Medellin Colombia Other
address: Phone.: 13-13-136131 13-13-13-1313 E-mail: anada@13.co Web page: Category: 3. Private sector Notes:
Atodo - Asociación de todo Address: calle 12 Bogota Colombia
Other address: Phone.: 12-1-23-32  E-mail: Web page: www.atodoooo.com, Category: 99. Public sector Notes: note that there are missing fields.
```

I would like to obtain a matrix with column names to be converted as a .csv file as:

```
Company, Address, Other Address, Tel, E-mail, Web page, Category, Sector, Notes
```

And rows:

```
Anada - Asociación de nada, calle 13 13 Medellin Colombia, 13-13-136131 13-13-13-1313,anada@13.co,,3,Private,,

Atodo - Asociación de todo,calle 12 Bogota Colombia,,12-1-23-32,www.atodoooo.com,99,Public,note that there are missing fields.
```

How can it be done with R?

Answer (score 2):

It might be tedious but it seems like it would require string processing.

```
splitlist = 'Address|Other address|Phone|E-mail|Web page|Category'  
a = str_split(text[1], ':')  

for (i in 1:length(a[[1]])) {  
 a[[1]][i] = str_replace_all(a[[1]][i], splitlist, "")  
}  

# [[1]]
# [1] "Atodo - Asociacin de todo "           " calle 12 Bogota Colombia "          
# [3] " ."                                   " 12-1-23-32  "                       
# [5] " "                                    " www.atodoooo.com, "                 
# [7] " 99. Public sector Notes"             " note that there are missing fields."
```

Then you can extract each field with less string processing.

I cannot think of any simpler method other than regex in this case.

Comment: Thnaks, but it does not solve my problem with multiple cases.

Comment: What would solve my problem (except for first item), is  text<-(c"include text here"); a = strsplit(text, " ") and then, which (text=="Notes: "); and which (text=="Adress"), and then a way to select text in between. and then unlist(text in between)

Answer (score 1):

The following *assumes* that your records are on one line per entry, that is that it looks something like:

```
text <- c("Anada - Asociación de nada Address: calle 13 13 Medellin Colombia Other address: Phone.: 13-13-136131 13-13-13-1313 E-mail: anada@13.co Web page: Category: 3. Private sector Notes:", 
          "Atodo - Asociación de todo Address: calle 12 Bogota Colombia Other address: Phone.: 12-1-23-32  E-mail: Web page: www.atodoooo.com, Category: 99. Public sector Notes: note that there are missing fields.")
```

If not, but if we can assume that the "`Address:`" field would always be on the first line, we can do something like this:

```
## Starting point
text <- c("Anada - Asociación de nada Address: calle 13 13 Medellin Colombia Other", 
          "address: Phone.: 13-13-136131 13-13-13-1313 E-mail: anada@13.co Web page: Category: 3. Private sector Notes:", 
          "Atodo - Asociación de todo Address: calle 12 Bogota Colombia", 
          "Other address: Phone.: 12-1-23-32  E-mail: Web page: www.atodoooo.com, Category: 99. Public sector Notes: note that there are missing fields.")

## Locate the elements that have "Address:" and use cumsum to get an index
## Use tapply to paste the relevant vector elements together into single strings
text <- tapply(text, 
               cumsum(grepl("Address:", text)), 
               paste, collapse = " ")
```

---

From there, the approach is essentially as follows:

- Extract a `list` of the "header" portions.
- Extract a `list` of the relevant values.
- Put those back together as a vector.
- Split them up again.
- Reshape the result from a "long" format to a "wide" one.

Tools used are as follows:

```
library(devtools)
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
source_gist("11380733") ## For cSplit
```

The approach starts similarly to @won782's.

```
splitlist <- c("Address:", "Other address:", "Phone.:", "E-mail:", "Web page:",
               "Category:", "Public sector Notes:", "Private sector Notes:")
pattern <- paste0(splitlist, collapse = "|")
```

I find some of the the "stringr" functions to be somewhat slow, so sticking with base R:

```
X1 <- regmatches(text, gregexpr(pattern, text))
X2 <- regmatches(text, gregexpr(pattern, text), invert = TRUE)

Combined <- Map(paste0, 
                lapply(X1, append, values = "Company:", after = 0), 
                lapply(X2, data.table:::trim))
```

Here's where we are so far:

```
Combined
# [[1]]
# [1] "Company:Anada - Asociación de nada"    "Address:calle 13 13 Medellin Colombia"
# [3] "Other address:"                        "Phone.:13-13-136131 13-13-13-1313"    
# [5] "E-mail:anada@13.co"                    "Web page:"                            
# [7] "Category:3."                           "Private sector Notes:"                
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Company:Atodo - Asociación de todo"                     
# [2] "Address:calle 12 Bogota Colombia"                       
# [3] "Other address:"                                         
# [4] "Phone.:12-1-23-32"                                      
# [5] "E-mail:"                                                
# [6] "Web page:www.atodoooo.com,"                             
# [7] "Category:99."                                           
# [8] "Public sector Notes:note that there are missing fields."
```

The `cSplit` function works nicely with `data.table`s, so let's use that directly.

```
DT <- data.table(V1 = unlist(Combined))       ## unlist the values
DT <- cSplit(DT, "V1", ":")                   ## Split by a colon
DT[, V1_1 := gsub("Public sector |Private sector ", "", V1_1)]  ## Just "notes"
DT[, id := cumsum(V1_1 == "Company")]         ## Add an id column
```

From there, we can use `dcast.data.table` to transform the dataset from a "long" one to a "wide" one, like this:

```
dcast.data.table(DT, id ~ V1_1, value.var = "V1_2")
#    id                       Address Category                    Company
# 1:  1 calle 13 13 Medellin Colombia       3. Anada - Asociación de nada
# 2:  2      calle 12 Bogota Colombia      99. Atodo - Asociación de todo
#         E-mail                               Notes Other address
# 1: anada@13.co                                  NA            NA
# 2:          NA note that there are missing fields.            NA
#                        Phone.          Web page
# 1: 13-13-136131 13-13-13-1313                NA
# 2:                 12-1-23-32 www.atodoooo.com,
```

Comment: Thank you, but assuming a one line per entry is not correct. The example above contains two entries, but they are not divided in lines.

Comment: all entries in an unformated text, however it should be easy to convert the   text to one line per entry. Which would be the easiest way?

Comment: @xav, is it likely that "Address:" would always be in the first line of an entry? If so, then it should be an easy fix.

Comment: I have seen that the text you converted was already split. Here is the text as it should be:

Comment: c("Anada - Asociación de nada Address: calle 13 13 Medellin Colombia Other
address: Phone.: 13-13-136131 13-13-13-1313 E-mail: anada@13.co Web page: Category: 3. Private sector Notes:
Atodo - Asociación de todo Address: calle 12 Bogota Colombia
Other address: Phone.: 12-1-23-32  E-mail: Web page: www.atodoooo.com, Category: 99. Public sector Notes: note that there are missing fields.")